# EPPLUS exporting data from excel to word document

Tags: c#, wpf, epplus

I am working on exporting a lot of data from excel file and put it into a word document 
so I add each cell into a list of objects then i use its index to return it back and there are a lot of null cells as well 
problem is sometimes the desired data shifts its index assuming we want to return the index of data3[25]

for some reason sometimes it comes at [27] or [23]  don't know why? what could be the problem

```
List<object> data2 = new List<object>();
List<object> data3 = new List<object>();


foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells)
{
    data.Add(cell.Value);
}

foreach (var cell in worksheet2.Cells)
{
    data2.Add(cell.Value);
}

foreach (var cell in worksheet3.Cells)
{
    data3.Add(cell.Value);
}
```

[this is what the excel sheet looks likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03plr.png)

Comment: Seems that you have some cells in the Excel sheet that is sometimes read, sometimes not. Maybe some logic in the excel sheet populates/add/remove cells based on other cell values? Only logical explanation I can think off.

Comment: thanks man that was right i solved that already